# Can't get external visibility on flask server

Tags: python, linux, flask

I'm running a server on python using flask, i've read the documentation but i still can't get external visibility.
Here's the code i'm trying to test.

```
@app.route('/api/v1.0/map')
def provideMap():
    response = {}
    response['url']=mappa
    response['bathrooms']=bathroomsState()
    result=jsonify(response)
return result;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=False)
```

When I open this html for testing from another pc in my LAN, i can't connect to the server, what i am missing?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.get( "http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1.0/map", function( data ) { //set the right url for the img (the url is sent by the server)
            url=data["url"];
            bathrooms=data["bathrooms"];
            document.getElementById("map").src="http://0.0.0.0:5000"+url
});


});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/prova.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <h1>Map</h1>
    <div id="mappa"><img id="map" src=""></img></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I open this html for testing from another pc in my LAN

In your server code `0.0.0.0`, means bind to all network interfaces. It does not represent the IP address of that server.

Therefore you cannot connect to  `http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1.0/map` from your client on a different machine as it is not a valid IP!

You need to find the correct IP address of your server, and then replace `0.0.0.0` in the client code with that. Since it appears you are using Linux as the server, open a terminal on the server and type

```
sudo ifconfig
```

Looks for the IP address listed under `eth0` (network cable) or `wlan0` (wireless internet)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that  in javascript you use 0.0.0.0 to access the server,
and you should use it's reall address or omit the servername at all.

Another option (the best solution for `$.get`) is to use `location.host` and `location.protocol`:

```
$.get( location.protocol + location.host + "/api/v1.0/map", 
...
```

Comment: He mentions he's accessing from a different PC on his LAN.